# Building a continuous integration tool

Tags: git, security, ssh, continuous-integration

Let's say I'm building a continuous integration tool where the user connects with their GitHub/GitLab account and choose a repository where the tool should be executed at every commit.
The tool consists of some find/replace script so the user code will not be executed.

For each repository enabled I create an SSH key pair, store it in the database and add it as a deploy key using the GitHub/GitLab API.

Now every time one of this repository gets a new commit a webhook is called which need to clone the repository using the custom SSH key in the database.

What would be the most convenient way to clone this repository? The service would need to handle a lot of different ssh keys so altering the `~/.ssh/config` file is not comfortable.

I was thinking about using a docker script but it might be slow and overkill as I don't think I need a virtualized environment.

Note that I will not execute the cloned code, just read it.

Comment: This sounds like you might want to look at      
`AuthorizedKeysCommand` in `sshd_config` which lets you specify a comnmand used to retrieve keys from e.g.a database.